# Retrieving more then one object with values from Db in asp.net webapi

Tags: c#, sql, npgsql

I am learning asp.net webapi and trying to get values for different object.I have a function called

> SELECT * FROM test.get_accounts_info('CS-01')

which returns 5 columns.

- account_number [value- CS-001]
- account_name   [Sam]
- product        [Test]
- interest_rate  [1]
- balance        [1000]

  Now in my controller i am passing an object of AccountInfo Class.

  ```
  [HttpPost]
  [ActionName("info")]
  public IHttpActionResult GetAccountInfo([FromBody]AccountInfo 
       accountinfo)
  {
      accountinfo.accountNumber = BusinessLayer.Api.AccountHolderApi.GetAccountInfo(accountinfo.accountNumber);
      return Ok(accountinfo);
  }
  ```

The AccountInfo Class

```
    public class AccountInfo
      {
        public string accountNumber { get; set; }
        public string balance { get; set; }
        public int interestRate { get; set; }
        public string accountName { get; set; }
        public string accountType { get; set; }
      }
```

My Route

> config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("test", "v1/{controller}/{action}");

And the Db Layer code from where i am calling the function

```
      ` public static string 
        GetAccountInfo(string accountNumber)
        {
            var sql = "SELECT * FROM 
            test.get_accounts_info(@AccountNumber);";
            using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand(sql))
            {
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountNumber", 
               accountNumber);
               return Common.Conversion.TryCastString(DBOperations.GetScalarValue(command));
            }
        }`
```

Now in postman when i pass the value from the body like this

> {"accountNumber": "CS-001"}

In my response i get this

> {
>     "accountNumber": "CS-0000001",
>     "balance": null,
>     "interestRate": 0,
>     "accountName": null,
>     "accountType": null
>   }

Where i am wrong?Any Help Please.

**UPDATED**

My DBOperation.cs has these classes

```
  public static NpgsqlDataReader GetDataReader(NpgsqlCommand command)
    {
        if (command != null)
        {
            if (ValidateCommand(command))
            {
                command.Connection = Connection;
                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                command.Connection.Close();
                command.Connection.Dispose();
                return reader;

            }
        }

        return null;
    }



  public static object GetScalarValue(NpgsqlCommand command)
    {
        if (command != null)
        {

            if (ValidateCommand(command))
            {
                command.Connection = Connection;
                var val = command.ExecuteScalar();
                command.Connection.Close();
                command.Connection.Dispose();
                return val;

            }
        }

        return null;
    }





  public static bool ExecuteNonQuery(NpgsqlCommand command)
    {
        if (command != null)
        {
            if (ValidateCommand(command))
            {
                command.Connection = Connection;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                command.Connection.Close();
                command.Connection.Dispose();
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: The scalar value only returns the first column from the first row. Try the ExecuteReader, https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @user1408786 Where should i use it sir?

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with WebApi but everything to do with a really awkward and unflexible backend programming model that you choode to implement.

Comment: @TomTom working on already built on architecture sir..sorry

Answer (score 1):

Look at this example from: 
http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/npgsql_cs_result_sets

```
   using System;
   using Npgsql;

   class Sample
   {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         // Connect to a PostgreSQL database
         NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;User Id=postgres; " + 
             "Password=pwd;Database=postgres;");
         conn.Open();

         // Define a query
         NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT city, state FROM cities", conn);

         // Execute the query and obtain a result set
         NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();

         // Output rows
         while (dr.Read())
           Console.Write("{0}\t{1} \n", dr[0], dr[1]);

         conn.Close();
     }
   }
```

Keep the using and stuff you already have. Just update it to command.ExecuteReader, as this method reads all rows and columns. Execute Scalar is only returning the first column from the first row

Comment: still confused about the one you said above and my legacy backend code sir.because everything in my code is referenced from  DBOperations class.

Comment: I don't know DBOperations, is it a custom class? Why are you using the static method GetScalarValue? It sounds a bit strange for me to call something on a database with a static method.

Comment: I would remove that complete static class. And just open with a using statement for every database call a connection. But just to get it working, try to add a method with ExecuteReader, based on the example I posted.

Comment: command.Connection = Connection;
                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                command.Connection.Close();
                command.Connection.Dispose();
                return reader;

you are closing and disposing the connection before you have actually read it.

Comment: public static string GetAccountInfo(string accountNumber)
        {
            var sql = "SELECT * FROM sms.get_accounts_info(@AccountNumber);";
            using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand(sql))
            {
                command.Connection = Connection;
                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                command.Connection.Close();
                command.Connection.Dispose();
                return reader;
   I tried this

Comment: You cannot read it after you have closed and disposed the connection, see the example:

         // Execute the query and obtain a result set
         NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();

         // Output rows
         while (dr.Read())
           Console.Write("{0}\t{1} \n", dr[0], dr[1]);

         conn.Close(); 
The connection is closed after reading.

Comment: public static string GetAccountInfo(string accountNumber)
        {
                NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;User Id=postgres; " +
           "Password=pes;Database=pmc;");
                conn.Open();
                NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM sms.get_accounts_info(@AccountNumber);", conn);
                NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
                return dr.ToString();   did this sir and getting error as accountnumber column doesnot exist

Comment: You are still not using the while dr.read(), and also the select statement won't work.

NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM sms.get_accounts_info where AccountNumber = @AccountNumber;", conn); 
use the command.AddParameter to add the value of the parameter.

Comment: Can i use this SELECT * FROM sms.get_accounts_info where AccountNumber = @AccountNumber; because sms.get_accounts_info is a function in postgre?

Comment: Sorry I don't know about postgre, just first try to get it working without the Acount number, just select * from sms.get_accounts_info. If you just use the example I posted, and try to get data in that example first, it might be easier to understand and modify it for your case.

Comment: NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;User Id=postgres; " + "Password=pes;Database=pmc;");
 conn.Open();NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM sms.get_accounts_info(@AccountNumber); ", conn);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountNumber", accountNumber);NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read()) Console.Write("{0}\t{1} \n", dr[0], dr[1]); return dr.ToString(); Did this i am getting the output as {"accountNumber":"Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader",
  "balance": null, "interestRate": 0,"accountName": null,"accountType": null}

Comment: What result do you get when you execute it directly in sql without c#?

Comment: i get all the data associated with the passed account number as parameter in sql

Comment: You said you get this in the console: {"accountNumber":"Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader", "balance": null, "interestRate": 0,"accountName": null,"accountType": null} How does it differ from the result you expect? What are you expecting? What happens if you put a breakpoint in the while loop, so you can see if you can get somehow the data you expect from dr

Comment: i am on webapi project and i am posting accountNumber as param in there sir..alright i am doing it in console now.sorry

Comment: NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;User Id=postgres; " +"Password=pes;Database=pmc;");
conn.Open();NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * from sms.customer_sms", conn);
NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();   while (dr.Read())
Console.Write("{0}\t{1} \n", dr[0], dr[1]); conn.Close(); Hello sir i tried this and get the output..the thing is how do i pass the parameter.in this i simply queried a table data with execute reader and it worked well.

Comment: I think something like this, which you have tried should work:
NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM sms.get_accounts_info(@AccountNumber)", conn); command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountNumber", accountNumber) First try it in normal sql without c#, if that works than try it in c#

Comment: Earlier i tried it in console without the param and it worked..now with param like you said to do it in normal sql without c#.. I didnot understand "without c#" part?do you mean in query editor or?

Comment: Yes it works in query editor..in query editor running select * from sms.get_accounts_info(CS-001) does gives the output and correct values for the 5columns.